# Isomorphism class of an $\operatorname{Aut}(G) $-torsor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over a field $k$ and $x\in X$ a geometric point.

Let $G$ be connected reductive group over a $k$ and let $\underline{G} = G\times X$ étale-locally.

> The data of $\underline{G}$ induces an $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$-torsor $\tau \to X$ such that its isomorphism class is an element of $H^1(\pi_1^{ét}(X,x), \operatorname{Aut}(G)(\overline{k}))$.

Does it come from the bijection $\operatorname{Hom}_{cont}(\pi_1^{ét}(X,x),G)/Inn(G) \cong Tors(X_{Fl},\underline{G})$? How to see that?